# Is there an assembler that will let me 'inline' machine code?

Tags: assembly, machine-code

I've done lots of looking on Google for a way that you could include machine code right inside of an assembly source file. I haven't had any luck.

What I mean by 'inline machine code' might be unclear, so let me provide you with an example of what I'm looking for:

```
; here's my normal assembly code...
mov eax, 8
add eax, 10
; now I would like to be able to add some machine code
__machinecode__("40") ; this is equivalent to 'inc eax' (I think!)
```

So, that's it.

Comment: great question !! just out of curiosity WHY WOULD YOU EVER WANT TO DO THAT?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов There are different possible reasons. It may be that the assembler is old and doesn't support some newer instructions. It may be that one wants to test their disassembler or emulator and needs to be sure that, for example, both encodings of `mov eax, ebx` are covered and the different order of instruction prefixes is covered and invalid instructions are covered and so on. Yet another reason is using code as data (for example, to compact your 256-byte assembly demo) and you need to be sure you've got the right encoding. There are other reasons too.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze pretty awesome reason! thank you!

Comment: did you mean 40 hex?  .byte 40h?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов It's also possible to use "double code" (I wonder what's the correct English word), I mean code with more than one possible decoding depending on the start offset of the execution (with a jump or call to 2nd or later byte of instruction to get other "hidden" instructions). For example, in x86-64: `db 'jH5j6j7'`: `push 0x48; xor eax, 0x376a366a`. `db 'H5j6j7'`: `xor rax, 0x376a366a`. `db 'j6j7'`: `push 0x36; push 0x37`... Other reason may be that some assemblers may not support some undocumented instructions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All assemblers I know of have such a feature.

```
mov eax, 8
db 90h ; this is "nop"
add eax, 10
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Lemme just try this out, then I'll accept.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 first you will answer my question

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов That's impolite. But you may have my answer instead of his.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I'm running into some trouble trying to do this in GNU Assembler, can you look at my question again?

Comment: What if you drop all the money on the floor? I mean the dollars.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Won't be picking that money back up, thanks, now it works!